# PHP variable "default value"

Tags: php, variables, default-value

I want to get a value from the session, but use a default if it is not defined. And ofcourse I want to circumvent the PHP notice.

You can write a function that does this

```
function get(&$var, $default){
    if(isset($var)) return $var;
    return $default;
}

echo get($foo, "bar\n");
$foobar = "foobar";
echo get($foobar, "ERROR");
```

[Example in action](http://codepad.org/FzTPuvBO)

Is there a way to do this without defining this function in every file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From PHP 7, you can now use the null coalescing operator :

```php
$var ?? $default
```

that does exactly like your function

Answer (score 10):

You can define it in one script and then `require_once` that script in your other scripts

You could also just use the ternary operator:

```
$myVar = isset($var)?$var:$default;
```

Comment: Yeah -- are you intending to add it to the language?

Comment: That is not possible (for me) ofcourse, but I thought there might be a language built-in alternative

Comment: Well you can include the same script in several different projects.  I might be missing the spirit of the question here, though.

Comment: What about the ternary operator?  I just added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use this concise alternative:

```
isset($myVar) || $myvar=$default;
```

The `||` operator is short circuit, it will not evaluate second operant if the first one be evaluated true.

Comment: Please include an explanation of why you think your code solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) has been added to PHP version 7.0, what it does is replaces

```php
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';
```

with a shorter version:

```php
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
```

What the line above does, is check if `$_GET['user']` is set, and not null, then it will assign that to the `$username` variable, if `$_GET['user']` is not set (and thus null) it will default to the `'nobody'` string so `$username` is `nobody`.

Your code should look like:

```php
echo $foo ?? "bar\n";
$foobar = "foobar";
echo $foobar ?? "ERROR";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use less code to do what you need.

You don't need to specify the variable again using the `_?_:_` format.

```
echo $var?:"default";
```

Is the same as

```
echo $var?$var:"default";
```

Now as far as an empty check, you could use `@` to mute notices, I'm not sure of the technical ramifications, but you're already doing your own checking while using this format:

```
echo @$non_existing_var?:"default";
```

Some examples:

```
<?php

    $nope = null;
    $yup = "hello";
    echo ($nope?:$yup) . "\n" ;
    echo ($yup?:$nope)  . "\n" ;

    $items = [ 'one', 'two', false, 'three', 'four', null ];

    foreach($items as $item):
        echo($item?:"default shown (".var_export($item,true).")")."\n";
    endforeach;

    echo(@$non_existing?:"default for non-existant variable!");

?>
```

Output:

```
$ php variabledefault.php
 hello
 hello
 one
 two
 default shown (false)
 three
 four
 default shown (NULL)
 default for non-existant variable!%
```

Comment: This is incorrect: `$v=false; echo $v?:"not set";` will incorrectly yield "not set"

Comment: Yes, so it is not the answer to the question. The question was "Show a default if the variable is not set", not "Show a specified value if the variable evaluates to `false`"

Comment: "I want to get a value from the session, but use a default if it is not defined. And ofcourse I want to circumvent the PHP notice."

This can be achieved exactly as requested by using (if the 'derp' session variable is not set): `print @$_SESSION['derp']?:"default";`

That said, yes, if it's false, it will return the default, but that's how logic works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, for example:

```
$myVar = ValueResolver::resolve($var, $default);
```

and don't forget to use namespace `use LapaLabs\ValueResolver\Resolver\ValueResolver;`

There are also ability to typecasting, for example if your variable's value should be `integer`, so use this:

```
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('6 apples', 1); // returns 6
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('There are no apples', 1); // returns 1 (used default value)
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) for more examples